# Executing function after async operation has been performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm having some issues because I'm trying to re-use code (which can be used) in other parts of my application.

Now, I'm having the common:

```
$.ajax({
   url: JSONurl,
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   data: params,
   success: function(data){
      // do stuff after the result is retrieved
   }
});
```

The stuff is going fine but I would want to do something like that:

```
function ultramegafunction (){
    var ajax_data = asyncAjaxFunction();
    // When ajax_data is filled do other stuff
}
```

In that way, I could use the `asyncAjaxFunction()` in other functions where it's needed without having to rewrite all the code and putting specific things in the success part.

Do someone knows how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuerys `Deferred` objects which implicitly are mixed into the jXHR object. Therfore you need to `return` the jXHR object and then also bound handlers at some other place.

```
function asyncAjaxFunction() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: JSONurl,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: params,
        success: function(data){
           // do stuff after the result is retrieved
        }
    });
}
```

and somewhere else

```
function ultramegafunction (){
    asyncAjaxFunction().done(function( ajaxData ) {
        // When ajax_data is filled do other stuff
    });
}
```

Ref.: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: And where is the data stored?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna: not sure what the question is, but the result from the ajax request is also passed into the `done()` handler. I gave it the name `ajaxData` in the snippet above.

Comment: Ahh okay so that's what I was trying to achieve. I didn't knew about that! Thank you very much @jAndy

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
"asyncAjaxFunction" = function(options){
    var xhr = $.ajax( {
        'url' : options.url,
        'dataType' : (options.dataType) ? options.dataType : 'JSON',
        'type' : (options.type) ? options.type : 'GET',
        'async' : (options.async) ? options.async : false,
        'data' : (options.data) ? options.data : '',
        'cache' : (options.cache) ? options.cache : false,
        'success' : (options.success)? (options.success) :function(data) {
        },
        'error' : (options.error)? (options.error) :function() {
        }
    });
    return (xhr.status === 200) ? xhr.responseText : '';

}
```

Now you can call asyncAjaxFunction() from any where with appropriate parameters.